# Sublime Text HTML element folding arrow

Tags: html, sublimetext, sublimetext3

The fold arrow in the gutter doesn't have arrows for all indented elements in HTML, only a few:

[image: Screenshot]

It only shows an arrow on line #2 and #6. This is with reindenting and --- "tab_size": 2, "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true --- in my user settings.

Is anyone else experiencing this? I have the fold arrows set to always show and it'd be so much faster to be able to collapse each respective HTML element when necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: Look at your line number 13 and before it

Comment: Not sure why line 13 is still sitting flush but even if I select all, cmd + [ until all lines are flush on the left and run Line -> Reindent, the only available collapsible arrows are on Line 2 and 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indentation must to be well done to have folding arrows :

[image: SublimeText]

**Preferences**

```
"tab_size": 4,
"tabs_small": true,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
```

Comment: As mentioned above, the indentation is perfect (at least, according to Reindent), so why wouldn't I be able to collapse at Line 4 via an arrow?

Comment: In my Sublime Text, all is done with correct indentation, so it can be a cause.

Comment: Hi Alex, I'd love to see a screenshot with the arrows in the appropriate spots, if you had a chance. Maybe it's just the editor or some other odd behavior. There are times when the top level section element isn't able to collapse by the arrow for no reason at all so I'm hoping to find a resolution!

Comment: It's best practice to use 2 spaces for indents / tabs: are you using a default tab instead? Maybe Sublime simply doesn't care about the indentation setting and only adheres to the Tab

Comment: Just adding my preferences for tabs

Comment: Thanks for updating. Your preferences is set to translate tabs to spaces, but from what I understand if you are seeing those vertical lines then the tabs aren't actually spaces.

Comment: I have the same preferences but "tab_size" is 2 and if I type out the exact same markup, I don't get the arrows. If I use tabs via the indentation settings in the lower right, however, I get them. I wonder if Sublime Text simply doesn't support 2 spaces with the collapsible arrows?

Comment: Very freaky, I tried with `"tab_size": 2` and [the arrows are still there.](http://i.imgur.com/QT9hN8Q.png)

Comment: That IS freaky. Do you have [these settings](http://i.imgur.com/YKWdnvw.png) after opening a new file?

Comment: Exactly the same, I see that you're on Mac, I heard some issues with code folding on Mac and ST3...

Comment: Ah. Naturally, there's a rare bug that only I seem to be facing. :-/ It looks like using tabs instead of spaces is my only option during regular workflow and will have to convert to spaces upon distribution until it's fixed. Thanks for your help, Alex!

Answer (score 0):

Reiterating to what Alex has said, if Indentation is what's causing this .. Have

```
[
    {"keys": ["f12"], "command": "reindent"}
]
```

in your user preferences. Ctrl+A and then f12 and see if you get the collapsing arrows.

Comment: This produces the same results as if I went to Line -> Reindent. But, it is nice to have that bound now. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help with the real issue. Glad to help in some other way though :p